Can't set up soft time limits in celery
I am learning celery and facing some problem. I am trying to set up celery task, which is called by user from telegram bot. I am trying to set up task_soft_time_limit, but it doesn't work.
celery_app.py:
from celery import Celery


app = Celery(
    'reminder',
    broker='redis://localhost:6379/1',
)


app.conf.update(
    task_soft_time_limit=3,
    worker_max_memory_per_child=300 * 1024,
)

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'check-reminders-every-minute': {
        'task': 'tasks.schedule_reminders',
        'schedule': 30.0,
    },
}

tasks.py:
import os

import telebot
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from celery_app import app
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded


load_dotenv()
CHAT_ID = os.getenv('CHAT_ID')
bot_token = os.getenv('BOT_API')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)


@app.task
def time_task():
    try:
        import time
        time.sleep(10)
        bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, 'task is finished.')
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, 'something went wrong.')

telebot.py:
from tasks import time_task
import os

import telebot
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from celery_app import app


load_dotenv()
bot_token = os.getenv('BOT_API')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def test(message):
    time_task.apply_async()

bot.polling(non_stop=True)

I call the Celery worker with celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -P eventlet command and call task from telegram bot, but the tusk waits 10 second and sends message, whereas i should recive an error message.
I tried to set up limits for the current task,
@app.task(max_retries=3, soft_time_limit=1)
def time_task():
    try:
        import time
        time.sleep(10)
        bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, 'task is finished.')
    except Exception:
        bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, 'something went wrong.')

but it didn't work either.

First, I never used eventlet in my life, so I could be completely wrong here. What I believe is happening is that you are blocking everything when you run time.sleep(). Test my theory by replacing time.sleep() with eventlet.sleep .

It didn't help. Celery doesn't raise a SoftTimeLimitExceeded error. My next step will be to start Celery in a Docker container, to get rid of the pool with 'eventlet'. Thanks by the way.

Could it be that you can't use conf.update() the way you do? Perhaps you should verify that the config was updated? I use app.config_from_object() in all of my Celery-based projects. Also what you can do is to annotate the task itself with @app.task(soft_time_limit=3) instead of using global configuration.

I ran Celery in a Docker container without the -p flag and it started working. I believe, that eventlet somehow blocks celery's time limits.
